# Add Amex to credit cards accepted in iATS payment processor

Tags: iats, iatspayments

iATS confirmed that they can accept AMEX, but the extension only provides VISA Mastercard and Discover. How can we add AMEX?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension accepts AMEX, but you may have configured things such that your CiviCRM does not -> /civicrm/admin/options/accept_creditcard?reset=1

Comment: Thank you Karin - I didn't realize it needed to be enabled in option lists!

Comment: Agree, that's a UX fail!